# Hibernate Table-Per-Subclass With Duplicate Column Names

Tags: hibernate

I have an application using a Hibernate table-per-subclass setup. Unfortunately, for auditing purposes, each table has two columns:

- LASTUPDATEDBY        VARCHAR(16)
- LASTUPDATEDTIME      TIMESTAMP

Mapping creates something in the parent and subclasses like this:

```
@Column(name="LASTUPDATEDBY")
public String getLastUpdatedBy() {
    returh this.getLastUpdatedBy;
}
```

The field is named the same in the parent and subclasses. Changing the column is not an option.

For completeness, this causes a MappingException:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity:
com.myapp.domain.subclass1 column: LASTUPDATEDBY (should be mapped with 
insert="false" update="false")
```

Can anyone help?

Jason

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
 @Column(name="LASTUPDATEDBY")
public String getLastUpdatedBy() {
    returh this.getLastUpdatedBy;
}
```

in the sub-class

Comment: It won't work. The parent table and each child table has that column, and it needs to be populated for auditing purposes.

Comment: But the sub-classes will inherit from the super-class?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, its a legacy database schema (and a legacy DBA).